# What could make an animal have hallucinogenic blood?

Tags: chemistry, biochemistry, drugs

The animal in question is not hallucinating, but instead the humans who drink the blood of the serpent experience an altered state of consciousness that’s used in shamanistic ritual.

What chemicals could exist in a functioning animals bloodstream so that when humans drink its unprocessed blood they hallucinate?

Comment: If its in the blood of the animal, either the animal is halucinating or the halucinogenic substance does not affect the animal. If it does not affect the animal, then why does the animal prodiuce it?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That’s why I’m asking. I’m trying to justify drinking blood in a creepy ritual to cause hallucinations and I’m not aware of how it could plausibly work.

Comment: This could have a simple answer, but I haven't nearly the biology/chemistry/pharmacology background necessary to rationalize what I'm about to say. I wonder if consuming, for example, Cocaine or chewing Marijuana would leave enough of the drug in the blood stream that, for a short period, the blood itself could be a source of the drug? I simply don't know enough about how the drugs actually breakdown in the body. But if they do get into the bloodstream in a re-consumable way - that's your path to success. Animals that eat narcotic plants that are immune due to evolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It isn't the blood, it's the poison.

You see, things like hallucinogens in animals and plants usually aren't there to give whatever eats them a good time, but to ideally either kill it or, even better, convince it to never attack it again. This is well seen in hallucinogenic mushrooms, peppers, frogs, pufferfish and many others. It's just that sometimes, instead of working as intended, the species hurting them ends up being into it.

Despite this original defense purpose, there's 2 teeny tiny problems with leaving such a chemical in your blood:

1- it'd be at a risk of affecting you too all the time and probably being diluted throughout the blood and/or filtered out, meaning you'd also need to constantly produce it so it'd remain present in high enough quantities to be effective against something eating you, while also making sure you're completely immune to the effects of what you're using and in the doses you need it to remain.

2- for this to be effective, you'd need to get wounded so your blood could flow into the mouth of what's trying to eat you. Problem: that means your defense mechanism can only work if you get wounded enough, and that you need to loose valuable blood.

Overall, this is not a good thing, at all. This defensive mechanism is costly and harmful to you when it should allow you to escape an attack mostly unscathed.

So what's happening? Probably something similar to a [tiger keelback snake](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/the-snake-that-eats-toads-to-steal-their-poison#:%7E:text=The%20tiger%20keelback%20lives%20in,airways%20and%20affect%20heart%20muscle.), where the snake instead has glands all over its body capable of storing and releasing the hallucinogenic defense chemical when needed.

So why do they think it's the blood? Probably because they're accidentally causing the fluid in these glands to mix with the blood as they prepare the snake, not unlike someone failing to properly preparing a [fugu pufferfish](https://delishably.com/meat-dishes/Why-Japanese-Fugu-Sushi-Can-Kill-You), except in this case the improper preparation causes the shaman to get a high instead of getting a burial.

So overall, chances are that it isn't the blood, because having any kind of hallucinogen there constantly makes little sense out of having it for defense, and even then it's a poor defense since you can't use it without getting hurt (there is one type of lizard that utilizes its very blood as a defense, the horned lizard, but it's usually meant to scare off predators instead of poisoning them, as the lizard squirts it out of its eyes into the predator's face). If the animal has glands storing the chemical (could be any naturally found hallucinogen), then it makes sense why it'd have it and how it can end in the blood, while also explaining why preparing the snake in certain ways is important, as you want not to miss the glands (perhaps there's even a need to watch how many glands you open up as you prepare the snake, since depending on what's the hallucinogen, the animal might have enough psychedelics in it to kill the shaman via overdose).

Comment: I’m choosing your answer because the tiger keel back snake and pufferfish are absurdly good examples and satisfyingly solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Dolphins are known for playing with puffer fishes for the sole purpose of getting stoned with a gas they produce.

You can have something similar.